# Problems with subversion (in gnome keyring, maybe), user=null

Tags: 10.04, keyrings, svn, gnome-keyring

I'm having a problem with my subversion in Ubuntu, and it's happening only on my computer, my colleagues are working fine. It asks for password for user "(null)":

> Password for '(null)' GNOME keyring:

entering the password it shows:

> svn: OPTIONS of
>   'http://10.0.203.3/greenfox':
>   authorization failed: Could not
>   authenticate to server: rejected Basic
>   challenge (http://10.0.203.3)

What can be causing that (again: it's just on my computer, the svn server is ok).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/473139).

The following should solve the issue:

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Comment: Could you add more information like: Any work arounds, why this bug exists, etc? Just pointing out that it's a "bug" doesn't constitute much of an answer.

Comment: solved with this comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/473139/comments/9

Answer (score 2):

I run into this issue in my

- Xubuntu 11.10 and SVN 1.6.12
- Xubuntu 12.04 and SVN 1.6.17

every now and then (no idea what triggers the issue).

The magic that I found from the comments to the Javier González' answer is:

```
$ rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Posted as an answer so that I'll find this faster next time ...